# How do I prevent a foreign domain pointing to my server's IP from loading my website?

Tags: domain-name-system, haproxy

I have found that a random domain has set its DNS records to point to my server's IP address, which is a HAProxy load balancer in front of 4 apache servers. How do I prevent HAProxy from accepting requests from this domain, and only allowing requests to the legitimate domain?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? which DNS records? are you wanting to make sure that your server only responds positively to HTTP GET requests for your domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `frontend` definition in your HAProxy config:

```
frontend bla bla bla
<other settings>

#all HTTP traffic must use the correct site name
acl host-mysite hdr(Host) -i mysite.example.com
redirect location http://mysite.example.com/ if !host-mysite

<more settings for frontend>

backend foo
<backend config>
```

You could also outright block it if you prefer by using:

```
#block if request isn't for mysite
acl host-mysite hdr(Host) -i mysite.example.com
block if !host-mysite
```

Answer (score 7):

Filter on the value of the `Host` HTTP header, e.g. `hdr(Host) -i myhost.example.tld`.

Comment: In iptables, or the HAProxy config, or where?

Comment: In the HAProxy ACLs.